# Subscribe when two events with preconditions were fired within a timespan

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a ValueChanged event.
I want to subscribe to it using Rx only when Value > 5 followed by Value < -5 and both were fired within 5 seconds.

I have managed to create an observable that works with the Value condition.
How can I check if they were fired within 5 seconds?

Here's my code:

```
IObservable<MyEventArgs> data = Observable.FromEventPattern<...

var up = data.Where(ev => ev.Value > 0.5).Take(1);
var down = data.SkipUntil(up).Where(ev => ev.Value < -0.5).Take(1);

down.Subscribe(ar => { Console.WriteLine("OK"); });
```

[edit]:
Here is an image representing my input data and when the expected result should occure
[image]

[edit]:
On more thing:

Why I want this? ;-)
I'm trying to use WP7 accelerometer to detect up/down move that occurred within 'n' seconds and caused at least 0,5G (up) and less than -0,5G (down)

Thanks,
Bartek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on "up" and "down" assigned as above, how about the following code:

```
  var  updown=down.Zip(up,(d,u)=> d).Timeout( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 ) ).Retry();
  updown.Subscribe( ar => { Console.WriteLine( "OK" ); } );
```

I have not tested this yet, but maybe it is worth to try this.

Comment: So why it doesn't rise the TimeoutException? It's because of Retry()?

Comment: Yes this happens because of Retry() and after retry everything starts from the beginning. But please not that this solution will works only for hot observables!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
data.TimeStamp(anAppropriateSchedulerPerhapsDispatcherSchedulerOrTaskPool)
    .Buffer(2 /*items*/, /*advance by*/ 1)
    .Where(x => x[0].Value > 5 && x[1].Value < -5 && 
        x[1].Timestamp - x[0].Timestamp < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Found it!"));
```

Comment: I thought that Rx supposed to make life easier with events :-/ Thanks, I will try if it works for me

Comment: I have added an image which can explain my problem. I think you solution will not apply to this.

Comment: This certainly makes your life easier once you are family with the library in itself. And I do think the code above solves your problem.

Comment: @Christoph This problem is actually way tougher the way he's specified it now - the current code doesn't work since it's looking for a 5 *right next* to a -5. It basically means for every item yielded < -5, you have to keep a window for the last 5 seconds of items

Answer (score 0):

The `Join` operator is what you are looking for.

Based on your drawing, I assumed you wanted the window to be a fixed duration from the first consecutive high or low value.  The `RisingEdges` function (best name I could come up with on short notice) filters the source observable to these first consecutive values.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function RisingEdges(Of T)(source As IObservable(Of T),
                                  level As Func(Of T, Boolean)
                                 ) As IObservable(Of T)
    Return source.Select(Function(v) Tuple.Create(v, level(v))) _
                 .DistinctUntilChanged(Function(vb) vb.Item2) _
                 .Where(Function(vb) vb.Item2) _
                 .Select(Function(vb) vb.Item1)
End Function
```

From there, you can use the `Join` operator to find cases where these edges are close together.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function FindClosePeaks(Of T)(source As IObservable(Of T),
                                     high As Func(Of T, Boolean), 
                                     low As Func(Of T, Boolean),
                                     windowDuration As TimeSpan
                                    ) As IObservable(Of Tuple(Of T, T))
    Return Observable.Join(source.RisingEdges(high),
                           source.RisingEdges(low),
                           Function(h) Observable.Timer(windowDuration),
                           Function(l) Observable.Timer(windowDuration),
                           Function(h, l) Tuple.Create(h, l))
End Function
```

Beware of using this function with cold observables as there will be two subscriptions to it.  Depending on the source, this may be acceptable, or you may need to make it "hot" with `Publish`.

I wasn't entirely clear what you were looking for as a final result, but this should hopefully get you close to what you want.